# AngularJS TemplateURL isn't showing up- directive code is executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS app is not showing the contents of TemplateURL (test app running on localhost, not file://), and I can't get it to work on Plunkr either. Please help me find what I am doing wrong.

My element is like this:

```
 <div case-test=""></div>
```

With this directive, the text "HERE IS CASE TEST IN DIR" appears where it should:

```
 .directive('caseTest', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: 'HERE IS CASE TEST IN DIR',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log("Case test running")

        }
    };
});
```

But when I change my directive to this, the contents of case.html do not appear. The console.log runs and no errors appear:

```
.directive('caseTest', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateURL: 'case.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log("Case test running")

        }
    };
});
```

case.html is in the root directory of the web app, in the same folder as the app's index.html.

I stuck it in [a Plunkr where it also doesn't work, for your viewing pleasure](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y30PRr9e3Ue6qOA9B66O?p=preview). As you can see if you view console output, both directives run, but only the first one prints out its template.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct name of the property in which you can  refer to a template by URL, is `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nUrJverhY4HiJgJb0gt3?p=preview